# How to create 2 square waveforms of 50% duty cycle in 8051 with Assembly

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8051, proteus

I'm trying to create two square waveforms of 230 and 460Hz through p2.6 and p2.7 ports of 8051 in Proteus Simulation environment. It will also change its behavior with a switch input from p2.0. When switch is low, the behavior does not change. When it is toggled, frequencies interchange and duty cycle drops to 25%. I'm having trouble in the first part where switch is 0. Although my calculations are correct for the time delay and TH/TL values, the waveforms are not even closed to intended simulations. Also, the code should be strictly Assembly so C is not allowed.

I tried to recalculate but didn't work. I tried my approach with only one counter and it did work, so it has to do with timer triggering. In the code below, I check for timer flags and when a timer reaches its end, I complement the output for the 50% duty cycle. When I introduce the second one, the waveform changes and the expected period of 4 microseconds become few hundred miliseconds in the digital oscilloscope of Proteus.

Here is my code snippet:

```
ORG 0

    SETUP:
        ;both timers set as mode 1 (16-bit counter)
        MOV TMOD, #11H
    
    MAIN:
        MOV C, P2.0 ;switch signal moved to carry bit
        JC MODE1
    
    MODE0:
        ; This part corresponds to switch = 0. F2 gets timer 1, F1 gets timer 0
    
        ;initialize timer 0
        MOV TL0, #0FAH
        MOV TH0, #0F7H
        SETB TR0
    
        ;initialize timer 1
        MOV TL1, #17H
        MOV TH1, #0FCH
        SETB TR1
    
    LOOPM0:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JC MODE1
        JB TF0, TIMER0
        JB TF1, TIMER1
        SJMP LOOPM0
    
    TIMER0:
        CPL P2.6
        CLR TF0
        SJMP LOOPM0
    
    TIMER1:
        CPL P2.7
        CLR TF1
        SJMP LOOPM0
    
    MODE1:
        ; This part corresponds to switch =1, F1 gets timer 1, F2 gets timer 0
        ; To be implemented
    

    END
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Ekz.png) is my proteus setup:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the timer only at the beginning of the program. After overflow, you have to initialize it again because it counts again from the value `0x0000`.
You have to set `TLx` as soon as possible, otherwise you can lose one count.
You can shorten the program if you use the instruction `JBC` instead of `JB`.

Because it looks like a school assignment I won't write the correct code.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think fixing was that simple. There wasn't any information about needing to reassign TH/TL values after resetting TF in our lecture notes. The code works flawlessly now.

Comment: Ok, edit your post and insert the working code. The purpose of this website is to close questions with a working solution for others. And accept my answer as a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

After implementing mode 1 too, there was another issue. The waveform with 460Hz frequency interchanges between 25 and 50% duty cycles. I think the timer gets triggered a little early but my calculations are correct. So I do not know what is up with the latter part. However, first part (Mode 0) works flawlessly:

```
ORG 0

    SETUP:
        ;both timers set as mode 1 (16-bit counter)
        MOV TMOD, #11H

    MAIN:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JC MODE1

    MODE0:
        ; This part corresponds to switch = 0. F2 gets timer 1, F1 gets timer 0

        ;initialize timer 0
        MOV TL0, #0FAH
        MOV TH0, #0F7H
        SETB TR0

        ;initialize timer 1
        MOV TL1, #17H
        MOV TH1, #0FCH
        SETB TR1

    LOOPM0:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JC MODE1
        JB TF0, TIMER0
        JB TF1, TIMER1
        SJMP LOOPM0

    TIMER0:
        CPL P2.6
        ;Reset timer 0
        CLR TF0
        MOV TL0, #0FAH
        MOV TH0, #0F7H

        SJMP LOOPM0

    TIMER1:
        CPL P2.7
        ;Reset timer 1
        CLR TF1
        MOV TL1, #17H
        MOV TH1, #0FCH

        SJMP LOOPM0

    MODE1:
        CLR TF1
        CLR TF0
        SETB P2.6
        SETB P2.7
        ; This part corresponds to switch =1, F1 gets timer 1, F2 gets timer 0
        ;Setup for OFF1, F2
        MOV TL0, #21H
        MOV TH0, #0FAH
        SETB TR0

        ;Setup for OFF1, F1
        MOV TL1, #10H
        MOV TH1, #0FDH
        SETB TR1

    LOOPM1:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JNC MODE0
        JB TF0, STIMER0
        JB TF1, STIMER1
        SJMP LOOPM1

    STIMER0:
        CPL P2.7
        CLR TF0

        MOV TL0, #17H
        MOV TH0, #0FCH

        SJMP LOOPM2
    STIMER1:
        CPL P2.6
        CLR TF1

        MOV TL1, #0BH
        MOV TH1, #0FEH

        SJMP LOOPM2


    LOOPM2:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JNC MODE0
        JB TF0, STIMER00
        JB TF1, STIMER11
        SJMP LOOPM2

    STIMER00:
        CPL P2.7
        CLR TF0
        MOV TL0, #21H
        MOV TH0, #0FAH
        SJMP LOOPM1

    STIMER11:
        CPL P2.6
        CLR TF1
        MOV TL1, #12H
        MOV TH1, #0FDH
        SJMP LOOPM1



END
```